# Main Class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain],exit Code [1]

Tags: oozie, sqoop, cloudera-cdh

when I am trying to run sqoop workflow in cloudera CDH-5.3,its giving following error

> Main Class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain],exit Code [1]

I am trying to insert data into hdfs from Mysql DB.
I have copied the mysql jdbc driver into sqoop lib path and `/var/lib/sqoop` directory.

But still getting the error mentioned above.

Comment: If you can provide the stacktrace, it would be easier to understand the issue, also you `job.properties` file.

Comment: Please make sure that your are setting oozie.use.system.libpath to true in the job.properties file and that the sharelib is installed , also positing the stack trace would help a lot .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hue to create workflows, Go to Oozie Editor and edit the properties of the Sqoop action and add these Oozie properties:

```
oozie.use.system.libpath true
oozie.action.sharelib.for.sqoop sqoop
```

Comment: If the first property (`oozie.use.system.libpath`) is added, second is not required here. It is redundant.